# How to groupby column value using R programming

Tags: r, count, group-by

I have a table

Employee Details:

```
EmpID | WorkingPlaces | Salary
1001  | Bangalore     | 5000
1001  | Chennai       | 6000
1002  | Bombay        | 1000
1002  | Chennai       | 500
1003  | Pune          | 2000
1003  | Mangalore     | 1000
```

A same employee works for different places in a month. How to find the top 2 highly paid employees.

The result table should look like

```
EmpID | WorkingPlaces | Salary
1001  | Chennai       | 6000
1001  | Bangalore     | 5000
1003  | Pune          | 2000
1003  | Mangalore     | 1000
```

My code: in R language

```
knime.out <- aggregate(x= $"EmpID", by = list(Thema = $"WorkingPlaces", Project = $"Salary"), FUN = "length") [2]
```

But this doesnt give me the expected result. Kindly help me to correct the code.

Comment: What is the criteria to get the result

Comment: The criteria is the result table should have top 2 highly paid employees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(EmpID) %>% 
   mutate(SumSalary = sum(Salary)) %>% 
   arrange(-SumSalary, EmpID) %>% 
   head(4) %>%
   select(-SumSalary)
```

Comment: Actually I get error -> Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @MathuMathi  You need to install `dplyr` or `tidyverse`

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution. Considering your dataframe as `df`. We first `aggregate` the data by `EmpId` and calculate their `sum`. Then we select the top 2 `EmpID`'s for which the salary is highest and find the subset of those ID's in the original dataframe using `%in%`.

```
temp <- aggregate(Salary~EmpID, df, sum)
df[df$EmpID %in% temp$EmpID[tail(order(temp$Salary), 2)], ]

#  EmpID WorkingPlaces Salary
#1  1001     Bangalore   5000
#2  1001       Chennai   6000
#5  1003          Pune   2000
#6  1003     Mangalore   1000
```